# Why spring boot jpa hibernate projection throws exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

im working with spring boot, and trying to use projections since my classes are quite big, and there arent many times when i need all the data at once. So i went online and found Spring Boot's website who present projections. It should be pretty simple yes, but for some reason it throws this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested tuple value [index=0, realType=com.media.daos.ProjectDAO] cannot be assigned to requested type [java.util.Set]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.TupleBuilderTransformer$HqlTupleImpl.get(TupleBuilderTransformer.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.TupleBuilderTransformer$HqlTupleImpl.get(TupleBuilderTransformer.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter.convert(AbstractJpaQuery.java:324)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.lambda$and$0(ResultProcessor.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:228)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1033)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.springframework.data.domain.Chunk.getConvertedContent(Chunk.java:167)
    at org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl.map(PageImpl.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl.map(PageImpl.java:30)
...
```

I don't really get why because there is legit no talk about a java.util.Set in this query:

```
    @Value
    public class ProjectDetails {
        
        private String id, name, os, type;
    }

@Query(value = "select t.projects from TeamDAO t where t.name = :name", countQuery = "select count(p) from TeamDAO t inner join t.projects as p where t.name = :name")
    Page<ProjectDetails> getProjectsByName(@Param("name") String name, Pageable page);
```

PS: the count query is necessary, ive discussed this in another thread where it was the solution to an hibernate SQLSyntaxException. Even if it shouldn't be used, there is no reason for it to mess with projections so i dont know why it doesn't work
Any thoughts?

EDIT: per requested: ProjectDAO and TeamDAO

```
public class ProjectDAO extends BaseEntity implements DAO {
    
    @Value
    public class ProjectDetails {
        
        private String id, name, os, type;
    }
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2990447415589237412L;
    
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(length = 1024)
    private String description;
    
    private String features, os, type;
    
    @LastModifiedDate
    private long lastModified;

    @CreatedDate
    private long createdDate;
    
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;
    
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST , CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private Set<TeamDAO> teams;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST , CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private Set<ClientDAO> clients;
    
}

public class TeamDAO extends BaseEntity implements DAO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8649943850027398166L;

    @Column(length = 124, unique = true)
    private String name;

    private String leader;
    
    @LastModifiedDate
    private long lastModified;

    @CreatedDate
    private long createdDate;
    
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST , CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private Set<UserDAO> members;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "teams", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST , CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private Set<ProjectDAO> projects;
}
```

The `id` property comes from the BaseEntity class therefore doesn't show on this classes.
I have also considered it coult be the query, so instead of select t.projects i put `select t.projects.name as name, t.projects.id as id, t.projects.os as os, t.projects.type as type` but then says its `an illegal attempt to dereference collection`

Comment: You should show us ProjectsDao and TeamDAO. Its possible the relationship between the two is improperly defined.

Comment: @Deadron i edited the post with them. But could it really be that? I mean if i use ProjectDAO instead of the projection it works fine. Im just triying to avoid to get from Mysql and send through rest data i wont use in the case

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found it.
I Just had to rework my query. It was the problem i posted. The @Query annotation had to specify that i just wanted those variables. I changed the value of the query to the following:

```
@Query(value = "select new com.media.daos.ProjectDetails(p.id, p.name, p.os, p.type) from TeamDAO t inner join t.projects as p where t.name = :name", countQuery = "select count(p) from TeamDAO t inner join t.projects as p where t.name = :name")
```

Also i found that hibernate does not like nested classes, so ProjectDetails is a standalone class now. As in a new file

EDIT: Also from what i've read, implementing a mapper (not sure about which spring/hibernate class/interface you need to implement/extend) should work as well, but that maps the what comes from the db, therefore forcing the db to send everything while editing the sql, forces mysql to just send that. But don't quote me on this. If you want to do this, please do some research and fact check first